# Execl VBA: Any tips and/or suggestions for migrating from MSSOAPLib to MSXML2?

Tags: soap, excel, excel-2003, excel-2010, vba

I am migrating some spreadsheets from Excel 2003/WinXP to Excel 2010/Win7.

Some spreadsheets use the MS SOAP toolkit to retrieve data. MS drops the support of SOAP toolkit in Excel 2010. I am forced to move to MSXML2 library.

Anyone has done this sort of migration before? Is there any tips, suggestion or best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, It's been ages since I used SOAP (*Either in programming or other wise. I use GEL! LOL*)

Ok Jokes apart! You are quite right that the SOAP toolkit is obsolete now. Since SOAP calls to web service are just a `POST` with some `XML`, you should be able to do convert it easily.

I would recommend going through this blog by jpsanders.

**Topic: How to Send SOAP call using MSXML (replace STK)**

**Link**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2007/06/14/how-to-send-soap-call-using-msxml-replace-stk.aspx

Do let me know if you are still stuck. Simply post the code with which you are stuck and we will take it from there.

HTH

Sid